# Hanging a shelf using 3 wall-mounting brackets: How to align the drill holes?

Tags: drill, hole

Each bracket has 3 holes (two at the top, one at the bottom) and I'd like to align them to give me a proper horizontal (w.r.t. gravity) alignment. What's a reliable way to tell me where to drill? I only have a rather short level. The shelf (just a wood board) I'm trying to mount is approximately 4' long, the level I have is at most a foot long. In the past I've tried "extending" a level line by moving the level along but results have been... mixed.

Answer (score 2):

A helper would **really** help with a 4’ board

1. Screw one bracket into the wall (bottom hole only) 6” in from one edge where you would like the shelf
2. Place the other bracket 6” in from the other end
3. Place the shelf on the brackets and keep the brackets flat against the shelf
4. With the level on the shelf, raise or lower the bracket to find level
5. Screw in the second bracket in the bottom hole
6. Screw in the other holes and attach to shelf (ensure the shelf is centered first).
7. Maybe add a middle bracket, 3’ is a bit of a span depending on what you are putting in it

Comment: There's a middle bracket involved (3 brackets total). But yeah, that sounds like it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

With all due respect, get a 4' level... you'll use it for the rest of your life. They're 10 bucks at Home Depot.